# iOS 7 style calendar library for the whole year view feature

Tags: ios, iphone

I like iOS 7's new Calendar app, especially its "bird view" of every day in a whole year. I would like to include this feature in my app. Is there a library that already has implemented this calendar year view feature, or it's something I need to implement myself?

Comment: To those who think this is off-topic: I am not convinced by your reason of "they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam". It's not there are many options I want a recommendation of one. It's I cannot find a *single* library that meet my *programming* needs. It's a canonical programming question and help me understand how this could attract opinion or spam. It's your irresponsible down votes that make this great site sometimes abhorring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that this is the closest to your needs:
https://github.com/min/MNCalendarView

But you can browse for more here: [https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=✓&q=calendar](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar)

Comment: `MNCalendarView` is not ideal since it doesn't provide a single screen whole year view. However, I agree it's the best we can find so far. So I will accept your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @xiaobai You may want to check this lib too https://github.com/jumartin/Calendar

Comment: It has a full year view and looks great! Thanks for the cool work.